# linux kernel icmp implementation question

Tags: linux-kernel, tcp, icmp

in the current linux kernel,

when ICMP module receives ECHO REQUEST message, does it check or limit the data size?
or does it just puts the data in a new ICMP message and send back to the source?

I been reading the source code, and I am pretty sure the kernel doesn't check the data size but I want to make it sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct ICMP is not handling the size of the packet.

ICMP packet are contained in standard IP datagram. Since max size of IP is 65K. So the size check is done at IP level itself. ICMP layer need not worry about that in code.